# Need a Javascript Library for AJAX with multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, upload, multipartform-data

Could someone kindly point me to a small and simple AJAX library that will handle uploading multipart/form-data from inside a modal div.

Nothing wrong with JQuery, mootools, etc, but I'd prefer a pure JS solution to integrate with an existing Perl project which has legacy JS which is best not being changed.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Dojo - http://dojotoolkit.org/

Comment: Thanks. Interesting reading, especially regarding the AMD loader, etc. Not sure if I'd go this route yet due to the learning curve, but certainly not ruled out.